# Lumen: how can I get url parameters from middleware

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

This is my `routes.php`:

```
$app->get('/users/{id}/', ['middleware' => 'example', function () {
  return "users";
}]);
```

This is the `handle` function in the middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  // I would like to get the value of the url parameter {id} here

  return $next($request);
}
```

Is there a way I can get the parameter `id` from my middleware?

*** Edit ***

I'm using **Lumen 5.1.0**.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel but after a quick look I think you have to use the following method: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware#terminable-middleware . Could you give us the class definition? So, from which class are you inheriting?

Comment: @GuyT I'm not inheriting from any class, I'm following a very simple example as described here: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/middleware#defining-middleware. My middleware class in named `ExampleMiddleware` and it only have the method above. How the "terminable middleware" you linked can be useful for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some conventional ways in Laravel doesn't work on Lumen. And get parameter form URI in middleware is one of them. In Laravel, I just need to call `$request->id`, it will work like magic. But here in order to get parameter in Lumen, I need to do something like this:

```
$request->route()[2]['id']
```

Comment: I don't know which Laravel version you are using.Could you check this `$request->route()->parameter('id')`?

Comment: when calling $request->route(), it returns an array which has information about your routes such as which middleware you are using, which paramaters you pass. try `dd($request->route()`, you will see what I mean. Then the last index contains parameters which you passed through the route.

Answer (score 2):

If the `$request` value passed in is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`, which I think it might be, that class has a method called `input()`, which lets you do exactly that:

[image]

You should try this:

```
$id = $request->input('id');
```

Comment: I tried with `$id = $request->input('id');` but I get `null` inside `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

i think the latest lumen 5.6 official tutorial about middleware is no longer applicable, and out of date.